# How can I track how many installs of my Android App im getting thanks to an influencer?

Tags: android, facebook, analytics

If I give the playstore link to an influencer from Instagram of youtube, how I can track how many installs I'm getting out from him? Or at least, how many clicks to playstore.

My app have Facebook analytics because I use Facebook ads. (I'm running ads right now)

I know there is an "campaign attribution" section in Firebase analytics, but I don't think this will tell me exactly whats the origin of the conversion.

Comment: "campaign attribution" is exactly the process of determining the origin of a conversion.  Why do you think it's not suitable?

Comment: I have the playstore link on the description of my videos on youtube, if I put the link in the description of another video from another channel, would campaing attribution be able to tell me from wich channel the traffic is comming?

I think it would just tell me the total of installs coming from "youtube" as a global.

Comment: You need to add tracking parameters to the links: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#campaign-params